# Schengen visa application to go to Germany. Do I have to use VIDEX?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, ethiopian-citizens

I am an Ethiopian applying for a business visa to Germany. On their website (German embassy in Ethiopia), it states that I can apply using VIDEX.

The problem is when I fill the form some of the contents does not conform to our country. Can I just use Schengen visa application form to apply for visa?

Comment: Can you explain why "some of the contents does not conform to our country"? The form looks very general to me.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.